# Java Lambda to convert an Object[] array to a subset Object[] array

Tags: java

I have an initial array, `array1` which contains 30 elements and need to create a new array `array2` containing elements 0-14 from `array1`.

I'm using `IntStream` as the mapper for the array index. But the following gives errors:

```
Object[] array2 = IntStream.range(0,14).map(x -> (Object)array1[x]).toArray(Object[]::new);
```

Error on `(Object)array1[x]`:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<Object[]>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, `x` is a type of integer. You should use the `.mapToObj` instead `map` method.

```
Object[] array2 = IntStream.range(0, 14)
        .mapToObj(x -> array1[x])
        .toArray(Object[]::new);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Arrays.copyOfRange()` instead of `Stream`.

```
Object[] array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, 0, 14);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get first 15 (0-14) elements from an array to an array

```
List<String> first15ElementsList = Arrays.stream(arr)
.limit(15)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "To get first 15 (0-14) elements" OP would get the first _14_ elements, because `range(0, 14)` doesn't include 14 - that would be `range(0, 15)`, or `rangeClosed(0, 14)`.